# google storage error: Bucket is requester pays bucket but no user project provided

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I want to download files using "file.json" which includes all URLs.  Here I tried to use those code in Python, however I am getting this error:

```
  "code":400,"message":"Bucket is requester pays bucket but no user project provided"
```

I already set up my billing details when I created the GCP account. I really don't know how to solve it. I am not the owner of the bucket. I do have permission to get data from the bucket.
Python code:

```
 import os
 from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client

 os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'path/to/key.json'
 bq_client = Client()


 import json
 from google.cloud import storage
 client = storage.Client(project='my_projectID')
 bucket = client.get_bucket('the_bucket')

 file_json = bucket.get_blob('file.json')
 data = json.loads(file_json.download_as_string())
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the user_project in the request, which is a gcp project for which you have billing rights. The requests will then be charged to that project.

You can find a python code sample here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-requester-pays#using

```
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name, user_project=project_id)
```

See here for which permissions you need in the user_project: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/requester-pays#requirements

```
serviceusage.services.use
```

Comment: of course, I changed the storage.client thing. No difference

Comment: @vinsin - This answer is correct. What do you mean by **I changed the storage.client thing**? What change did you make and what is the error? Make sure that your identity has permission to charge your billing account linked to the **user_project=project_id**.

Comment: @vinsin note that the code sample in the docs passes the user_project on the bucket object creation while your code has it on the client_creation, I don't know if that is supposed to do the same thing.

If it still doesn't work I'd try using the gsutil code sample from command line, if that also fails you probably don't have the correct permissions in the second gcp project (the one that will be billed).

Comment: @somethingsomething thanks, I downloaded some files by using GCP SDK Shell without any problem. But I get a "Requester pays bucket access requires authentication" error (when I use Python), even though I log in with "gcloud auth login".